# When class static function load in memory?

Tags: php

I have a class like this.

```
<?php

namespace test;

class Test
{
    public static function static1(){}
    public static function static1(){}
    ...
}
```

And autoload use psr-4. 
when is the static function load in memory ?

- load with out use(include) ? I don't think it will do this.
- use test/Test(include php file) ?
- call Test.static1(); ?

In my option: static function is easy to use without `new`(of course, they don't have private data), but i afraid it's load more memory and make performance degradation.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  Why would a static method's definition require more memory than an instance method?   Also, what do you mean they don't have private data?  You can have private static properties and methods.

Comment: @Devon, Thank you for comment, I want know if use many static method it will run slower and  use more memory? And when the static method use memory. call or include php file? No private data is the reason why i use static method. because if each class instance have own data, I can't use static method(only can use static field).

Comment: I believe he is asking when does PHP load the static definitions. Like in C++ static classes are constructed and destructed at the beginning/end of execution for you. Since PHP is interpreted I would imagine static objects are loaded once they are seen.

Comment: You use class and method visibility when it **makes sense**, not when you *think* it might work faster. Do you choose white car color because it makes your car run faster? That's what you want to do. This question makes no sense in the real world, the parser parses the code, creates opcode and allocates memory **when necessary**, not because you made something static. Please consider removing this question.

Comment: imo, Without meaningful  measurements that you can explain why you did them and what they mean. You just have opinions based on a simple class and your belief of how PHP does it's stuff. seriously, go and do some measurements on your PC. It will surprise you? I have.

Comment: @N.B. Thank you for comment, If i have a tool class, and i will call so many times, use static method is better, no only for make sense.  Of couse, you are right, make sense is more important than performance.

Comment: @bassxzero Friend, you know me.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks, you are right. I will go and do some measurement on my PC. Before question, i have test some times but don't get what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: What you're asking/saying doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You need to research and correct your terminology and learn more about static methods or properties.  I believe when you're referring to private data, you're actually referring to "instance properties".

Static methods would use no more memory than an instance method, not sure where you came up with that idea.  The code of the class is loaded into memory by the compiler when it is **included**.  Except for their definition (compiled code), methods or functions do not use memory. The amount of memory consumed when a method is run depends entirely on what the method is doing.

Methods have no private properties, classes have private properties, and a static method can access private properties.

If your goal is to have a property persist across multiple instances, you can access a static property from within an instance method:

```
public function getData() {
    // self::$data or static::$data represents a static property $data
    return self::$data;
}
```

If your goal is to only have one instance of a class exist at any time, you can look up the Singleton pattern.

If anything, static methods and properties can be more efficient than instance counterparts.  One of the problems with static methods is they are less testable, you can do your own research on why you may want to avoid static methods, but performance is not likely one of the reasons.